# How to add .data attribute to dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating dynamically elements from `$.get` request, to each of created elements i have to add a data attribute with an object from that request.

So let's assume i have the following `$.get` request:

```
    $('.loader').show();
      $.get(api)
        .done(function (data) {

          let plu = [];
          data.map(d => {
            if (d.codplu == "COPERTI" || d.desc == "") return false;

            plu.push('<div class="card card-product" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalProduct" data-plu="' + d.id + '">')
            if (d.img) {
              plu.push('<img class="img-fluid" src="data:image/png;base64,' + d.img + '">')
            } else {
              plu.push('<img class="img-fluid d-none" src="">')
            }

            plu.push('<div class="card-body">')
            plu.push('<div class="row">')
            plu.push('<div class="col">')
            plu.push('<h5 class="card-title mb-0">' + d.desc + '</h5>')
            plu.push('</div>')
            plu.push('<div class="col-auto">')
            plu.push('<h5 class="text-right text-success price">' + formatPrezzo(d.prezzo) + '</h5>')
            plu.push('</div>')
            plu.push('</div>')
            plu.push('<p class="card-tag mb-0">')
            d.attributi.map(attr => {
              plu.push('<span class="badge badge-success mr-1" style="background-color: ' + toColor(attr.background) + '; color: ' + toColor(attr.text) + ';">' + attr.desc + '</span>')
            })
            plu.push('</p>')
            plu.push('<p class="card-text text-muted">' + d.estesa + '</p>')
            if (profilo.moduli.ordine_menu && profilo.tavolo != "0") {
              plu.push('<a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block add-cart cd-add-to-cart js-cd-add-to-cart" data-price="' + d.prezzo.toFixed(2) + '">' + AddToCartText() + '</a>') // BUTTON CREATED HERE
            }
            plu.push('</div>')
            plu.push('</div>')
          })
          $('#' + menu + '-tab > .card-columns').append(plu.join(""));
          $('.loader').fadeOut("slow");
        })
```

To each button created in each elements i have to add a `.data` attribute but how could i do it without iterating again through each button and by checking it's id to set the right `.data` attribute?

Comment: I'm confused by the question. You've already added a `data-price` attribute on the button; if you want to add another, do the same thing again with a different name and data in the same line of code.

Comment: @HereticMonkey actually till the data attribute was just some text it was okay to concatenate it but as i've read that by using `.data` it will not make the attribute visible to html and as the object i have to set in the attribute it's a large json i would avoid to set it as plain text

Comment: Exactly which data do you want to set to which element? It is not clear to me what you regards as the button...

Comment: @trincot at the right there is a comment // BUTTON CREATED HERE that's the button or  the one anchor with 'add-cart' class, the data to set is `d.varianti`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you use jQuery, use it to the full, and create all elements using the appropriate jQuery methods. This has as additional advantage that you avoid potential character escaping issues, and avoid accidental mistakes in opening/closing tags.

So here is how your code could be converted to more jQuery style. It is then also a breeze to call `.data` at the appropriate place:

```
$('.loader').show();
$.get(api).done(function (data) {
    $('#' + menu + '-tab > .card-columns').append(
        data.map(d => d.codplu == "COPERTI" || d.desc == "" ? ""
            : $("<div>", { 
                "class": "card card-product",
                "data-toggle": "modal",
                "data-target": "#modalProduct",
                "data-plu": d.id
            }).append($("<img>", {
                    "class": "img-fluid" + (d.img ? "" : " d-none"),
                    src: d.img ? "data:image/png;base64," + d.img : "",
                }),
                $("<div>").addClass("card-body").append(
                    $("<div>").addClass("row").append(
                        $("<div>").addClass("col").append(
                            $("<h5>").addClass("card-title mb-0").text(d.desc)
                        ),
                        $("<div>").addClass("col-auto").append(
                            $("<h5>").addClass("text-right text-success price").text(formatPrezzo(d.prezzo))
                        )
                    ),
                    $("<p>").addClass("card-tag mb-0").append(
                        d.attributi.map(attr =>
                            $("<span>").addClass("badge badge-success mr-1").css({ 
                                backgroundColor: toColor(attr.background),
                                color: toColor(attr.text)
                            }).text(attr.desc)
                        )
                    ),
                    $("<p>").addClass("card-text text-muted").text(d.estesa),
                    profilo.moduli.ordine_menu && profilo.tavolo != "0" 
                        ? $("<a>", { 
                            href: "#",
                            "class": "btn btn-outline-primary btn-block add-cart cd-add-to-cart js-cd-add-to-cart",
                            "data-price": d.prezzo.toFixed(2)
                        }).text(AddToCartText()).data(d.varianti)
                        : ""
                )
            )
        )
    )
    $('.loader').fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Comment: That's awesome, didn't knew that i could append simply jquery elements as it, would definitly use the same approach for all other `Ajax` calls i make to create elements from it's response. I'd have another question, is it a good practice to store in `data` attribute some array of objects?

Comment: Using data attributes like that is fine. Alternatively you would only use some id attribute and use a Map as lookup for all related data.

Answer (score 1):

The newly added elements are being added as raw HTML so, in order to call a jQuery method on them, you'd need to rewrite your code so every element comes from a variable.

An alternative is to find the new elements starting from the jQuery object you already have (as long as you have something that identifies them):

```js
const menu = "foo";
let plu = [];
plu.push("<div>One</div>");
plu.push("<div>Two</div>");
$('#' + menu + '-tab > .card-columns')
  .append(plu.join(""))
  .find("div:nth-child(1)").css({color: "green"}).data("data1", "value1").end()
  .find("div:nth-child(2)").css({color: "blue"}).data("data2", "value2").end()
;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo-tab">
  <div class="card-columns">Your items here:</div>
</div>
```